# What is the leveling margin error when using a level and the bubble is between lines but not perfectly centered?

Tags: level, leveling

Not sure if leveling works like all or nothing or there are degrees of levelness.
I would like to know what is the error margin of levelness (min is zero and max is ?) when your level shows the bubble between lines, it is not touching any one of them but you can see that it is closer to one of the lines

Comment: Trigonometry, longer the distance: bigger the error.

Comment: Usually depends on the length of the span   A small non perfect level in a foot usually does not matter.  10 or 20 feet you want it very close to perfect, a little off can mean an inch or two of drop.  To see the difference use a hanging picture frame, move it a tiny amount off level, then step back and see the difference with your eyes.

Comment: Of course, then you have the builder’s versions of straight, square and level…

Comment: Yeah it is trigonometry, the levelness is measured in degrees (it is an angle) and it does not change with the distance..so I am asking about the angle

Comment: Don't forget to check your level regularly. For a horizontal bubble, check a stable surface, then spin the level 180 degrees and see where the bubble goes. It should be in exactly the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a universal answer to your question.  Different levels are made to different tolerances.  One manufacturer says the best levels are accurate to 0.005 inches per inch, or 0.029 degrees. https://www.johnsonlevel.com/News/SpiritLevelInformation.  The guaranteed accuracy of a level should be noted on the packaging.

You should be able to figure out the answer for your particular level by placing it on a horizontal surface and shimming on one end with a feeler gauge until the bubble reaches one of the lines.  The thickness of the required shims divided by the length of the level will be the error, expressed as inches of error per inch.

Comment: yeah there is electronic ones that have a way to measure the angle as well.. I thought there would be a standard bracket imposed by the standard tolerance acceptable for this category of tools. Of course there is high precision ones as well